# Cannot Open Spyder From Anaconda Win10

Tags: anaconda, spyder

Getting This Error on Running Spyder

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\external\github.py", line 51, in 
    from urllib2 import build_opener, HTTPSHandler, Request, HTTPError
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib2'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 3285, in main
    mainwindow = run_spyder(app, options, args)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 3140, in run_spyder
    main.setup()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 809, in setup
    from spyder.plugins.console import Console
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\console.py", line 37, in 
    from spyder.widgets.reporterror import SpyderErrorDialog
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\widgets\reporterror.py", line 26, in 
    from spyder.widgets.github.backend import GithubBackend
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\widgets\github\backend.py", line 33, in 
    from spyder.utils.external import github
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\external\github.py", line 58, in 
    from urllib.request import build_opener, HTTPSHandler, HTTPError, Request
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTPSHandler' from 'urllib.request' (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py)

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) This look like an installation error, so I'd suggest you to uninstall Anaconda, remove by hand the `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3` directory (if it's still present) and the reinstall Anaconda again.

Comment: Tried it still no luck my other pc is runnning it without a problem so i am gonna use it there Thanks for the help